# How do I use v-model on none form-related elements?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-model

Before anything else, I'm using Vuetify's `VSwitch` component inside `my-component`. I want to return the value of `my-component` to the parent.

something like `<my-component v-model="returnedData"></my-component>`

Then the inside `<my-component></my-component>`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="John"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Andrew"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Melissa"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Elizabeth"></v-switch>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      toggledData: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to return the value of `toggledData` to the parent that's using it if possible. I've been browsing the net for a while and I've been seeing only with inputs. But it was possible to some of Vuetify's components like the `VTreeview`so I was thinking maybe it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent component listens to the child's changes with the `childToParent` and if there is any change I call the `childChanged ()` method

```
// Parent Component

<template>
  <div id="parent">
    <p>{{parentToggledData}}</p>
    <Child v-on:childToParent="childChanged"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child";
export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parentToggledData: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    childChanged(value) {
      this.parentToggledData = value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I listen to the changes on each `v-switch`, and if there is one, I call the `emitToParent ()` method in this method, I send the changes to the parent with `$emit` which takes as parameter the event listened by  the parent `childToParent` and "the value to send `this.toggledData`

```
// Child Component

<template>
  <div id="child">
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="John" @change="emitToParent"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Andrew" @change="emitToParent"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Melissa" @change="emitToParent"></v-switch>
    <v-switch v-model="toggledData" value="Elizabeth" @change="emitToParent"></v-switch>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  data() {
    return {
      toggledData: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    emitToParent(event) {
      console.log(event)
      console.log(this.toggledData)
      this.$emit("childToParent", this.toggledData);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `v-model` like in your example:

```html
<my-component v-model="returnedData"></my-component>
```

is (by default) equivalent to this:

```html
<my-component :value="returnedData" @input="returnedData = $event"></my-component>
```

Any component can support `v-model` just by having a `value` prop and emitting an `input` event. The names of the prop and event can be changed using the `model` option, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

All of this assumes that you want two-way data binding. In your question you seem to imply that you just want to pass data up to the parent, which is only one way. For that you only need to emit an event and listen for that event using an `@` listener.

Genuinely creating a two-way data binding would be tricky in this case. The easiest way is to drop the `v-model` on the `v-switch` and use the prop and event separately. There are alternatives, such as using `v-model` with a computed property that has a getter and setter, but I'm not convinced that would make things any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
`<v-switch @change="$emit('swithValue', value)" value="John"></v-switch>`
Then in your parent component just listen for `swithcValue` like `@switchValue="myFunction"` Your function implicitly gets the emitted value and you can do with it as you wish.